# In Recyclerview Image get misplaced while scrolling

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-recyclerview

I used customview contains ImageView and two TextViews, this is my RecyclerView.Adapter  I used Picasso library to show image.

```
 public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
         Picasso.with(context)
            .load(url)
            .placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder)   
            .error(R.drawable.error)   
            .resize(100, 100)                       
            .into(ivProfile);

    holder.tvFirstName.setText(object.getFirstName();
    holder.tvSecondName.setText(object.getSecondName);}


     public int getItemCount()
      {
        return profileListDetails.size();
      }

class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public TextView tvFirstName ;
    public TextView tvSecondName ;
    public ImageView ivProfile;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        ivProfile= (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.ivProfile);
        tvFirstName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvFirstName );
        tvSecondName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvSecondName );

    }
}
```

And my RecyclerView -

```
      <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView               
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true"
      android:scrollbars="vertical>

</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
```

Activity class is:-

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private RecyclerView rv_profileList;
private List<ProfilePOJO> profileList;
private RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
private RecyclerView.Adapter recycleAdapter;

 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile_list);

rv_profileList = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rv_profileList );
profileList = new ArrayList<>();

  getProfileDetails("");

 }


public void getProfileDetails(String ID) {

    RestAdapter adapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
            .setEndpoint(Constants.PROFILE_URL)
            .build(); 
         API objGetProfile = adapter.create(API.class);


    objGetProfile.getProfile(
             ID,
                           new Callback<String>() {
                @Override
                public void success(String result, Response response) {
                    try {

                        Gson gson = new Gson();
                        Type listType = new TypeToken<List<ProfilePOJO>>() {
                        }.getType();

                        profileList = (List<ProfilePOJO>) gson.fromJson(result, listType);

                        if (profileList.size() != 0) {

                            recycleAdapter = new ProductListAdapter(productList, MainActivity.this);

                            rv_profileList.setAdapter(recycleAdapter);

                                                    }
                                           } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }

                @Override
                public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
                    error.printStackTrace();
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity .this, "Please check Internet connection !", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }

            }
    );

}
}
```

The issue is when I am trying to scroll the recyclerview then image get alter changed,
can any one help me out.

Comment: What do you mean by "altered", their positions are changing? are different images displayed? or are they flickering ?

Comment: image get misplaced means position 1st images goes to position 3rd or position 4th image displayed to position 6th like any combination...

Comment: There positions are keep changing, but when click particular position to see details then right image is displayed.

Comment: In your `.into(ivProfile)` call,  is ivProfile a member variable or a typo?

Comment: If not a typo, change that to `.into(holder.ivProfile)`.

Comment: can you post complete adapter class? and the also way you initializing the adapter and informing adapter about data changes? (activity or fragment class )?

Comment: yes, I posted the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for respond guys...
Finally I have solved this

```
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
     Picasso.with(context)
        .load(url)
        .placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder)   
        .error(R.drawable.error)   
        .resize(100, 100)                       
        .into(ivProfile);
```

I have done change small change in above code...
In above code ivProfile declare as globally, so this is unable to link with ViewHolder reference. So I changed it like below...

```
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
     Picasso.with(context)
        .load(url)
        .placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder)   
        .error(R.drawable.error)   
        .resize(100, 100)                       
        .into(holder.ivProfile);
```